# Perl system command returns "mkdir /tmp/test.xxxxx: No such file or directory"

Tags: perl, redhat

I am trying to use Perl system command to ssh to another server and run the mkdir command but it always returns

```
mkdir /tmp/test.xxxxx: No such file or directory
```

while if I manually ssh and run the same command it works fine. Here is the code I wrote:

```
my $TEMPDIR = '/tmp/test.xxxxx';
system "$SSH $SSH_USER\@$TESTSVR \"mkdir $TEMPDIR\""  or die " $!\n";
```

Comment: I don't see what can be the problem. I tried a similar command here, and it worked fine. Can you try replace `mkdir $TEMPDIR` with `ls /tmp`. Does that work?

Comment: Why the extra pair of escaped quotes? Maybe your server or the ssh executable is looking for a command called "mkdir /tmp/test.xxxxx" rather than a command called "mkdir" with "/tmp/test.xxxxx" as an argument.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`system` doesn't return false on error. And `$!` isn't necessarily set on error, depending on what you call an error.

```perl
system(...);
die "Can't launch child: $!\n" if $? == -1;
die "Child killed by signal ".( $? & 0x7F )."\n" if $? & 0x7F;
die "Child exited with error ".( $? >> 8 )."\n" if  $? >> 8;
```

---

It's worth noting your have multiple code injection bugs which are easily fix by using the following:

```perl
system($SSH, "$SSH_USER\@$TESTSVR", "mkdir", $TEMPDIR)
```

Comment: Well, system passes through the exit code of the program, and most unix things use 0 to indicate success. However, system does not know or care if the thing actually worked.

Comment: @brian d foy. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using [Net::OpenSSH](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH).

It will take care of the little details (as, for instance, quoting or checking whether the remote command exits with a non zero value) for you:

```
use Net::OpenSSH;

my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new($TESTSVR, user => $SSH_USER);
$ssh->system(mkdir => $TEMPDIR)
    or die "Can't create remote dir: " . $ssh->error;
```